# Contrastive loss dose not change after some epochs

Tags: pytorch, loss

I am trying to implement a Contrastive loss for Cifar10 in PyTorch and then in 3D images. I wrote the following pipeline and I checked the loss. Logically it is correct, I checked it. But I have three problems, the first problem is that the convergence is so slow. The second problem is that after some epochs the loss dose does not decrease anymore and it is fixed. My third problem is that for some settings, it does not proceed anymore, I mean it sticks for some reason and I have to restart the kernel. I will be very thankful if someone can help me to say where I am doing a mistake. Thank you very much in advance.

````
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                                transforms.Normalize([0.491, 0.482, 0.447], [0.247, 0.243,0.261])])
class PairwiseAg(object):
    def __init__(self, transform):
        self.transform = transform
    def __call__(self, vol): 
        voli = self.transform(vol)
        volj = self.transform(vol)
        return(voli,volj)
dataset =datasets.CIFAR10('./data', train=True, transform=PairwiseAg(transform), download=True)
ss = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size= 0.2,random_state=0)
for train_idx, val_idx in ss.split(dataset):
    train_idx = train_idx
    val_idx = val_idx
train_set = Subset(dataset,train_idx)
val_set = Subset(dataset,val_idx)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_set,batch_size=512,shuffle=True,num_workers=2,drop_last=False)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_set,batch_size=512,shuffle=True,num_workers=2,drop_last=False)
device = torch.device('cuda:4' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = torchvision.models.resnet18(pretrained=False, progress=True)
model.fc = nn.Linear(in_features=512,out_features=128)
model = model.to(device)
class NT_Xent(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, temperature, device):
        super(NT_Xent, self).__init__()
        self.temperature = temperature
        self.device = device
        self.criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction="sum")
        self.similarity_f = nn.CosineSimilarity(dim=2)
    def forward(self, z_i, z_j):
        self.batch_size= z_i.size()[0]
        self.mask = torch.ones((self.batch_size * 2, self.batch_size * 2), dtype=bool)
        self.mask = self.mask.fill_diagonal_(0)
        for i in range(self.batch_size):
            self.mask[i, self.batch_size + i] = 0
            self.mask[self.batch_size + i, i] = 0
        z_i= F.normalize(z_i, dim=1)
        z_j= F.normalize(z_j, dim=1)
        p1 = torch.cat((z_i, z_j), dim=0)
        sim = self.similarity_f(p1.unsqueeze(1), p1.unsqueeze(0)) / self.temperature)
        sim_i_j = torch.diag(sim, self.batch_size)
        sim_j_i = torch.diag(sim, -self.batch_size)
        positive_samples = torch.cat((sim_i_j, sim_j_i), dim=0).reshape(self.batch_size * 2,1)
        negative_samples = sim[self.mask].reshape(self.batch_size * 2, -1)
        labels = torch.zeros(self.batch_size * 2).to(positive_samples.device).long()
        logits = torch.cat((positive_samples, negative_samples), dim=1)
        loss = self.criterion(logits, labels)
        loss /= 2 * self.batch_size
        return(loss)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=5e-1)
criterion = NT_Xent(0.7,device)
def train(epoch):
    model.train()
    total_loss = 0
    for i,(X,_) in enumerate(train_loader):
        X1 = X[0].to(device)
        X2 = X[1].to(device)
        h1 = model(X1)
        h2 = model(X2)
        loss = criterion(h1.float(),h2.float())
        total_loss+=loss.item()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backwar()
        optimizer.step()
    return(total_loss/len(train_loader.dataset))

def val():
    model.eval()
    total_loss = 0
    for i, (X,_) in enumerate(val_loader):
        X1 = X[0].to(device)
        X2 = X[1].to(device)
        h1 = model(X1)
        h2 = model(X2)
        loss = criterion(h1.float(),h2.float())
        total_loss+=loss.item()
    return(total_loss/len(val_loader.dataset))

def main(num_epochs):
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        tr_loss = train(epoch)
        val_loss = val()
       
output:
curren_lr:0.5
Epoch: 0 train_loss:0.0131  val_loss:0.0131
Epoch: 1 train_loss:0.0127  val_loss:0.0129
Epoch: 2 train_loss:0.0126  val_loss:0.0129
Epoch: 3 train_loss:0.0126  val_loss:0.0129
Epoch: 4 train_loss:0.0125  val_loss:0.0129
Epoch: 5 train_loss:0.0124  val_loss:0.0128
Epoch: 6 train_loss:0.0124  val_loss:0.0126
Epoch: 7 train_loss:0.0123  val_loss:0.0127
Epoch: 8 train_loss:0.0123  val_loss:0.0125
Epoch: 9 train_loss:0.0123  val_loss:0.0127
Epoch: 10 train_loss:0.0123  val_loss:0.0126
Epoch: 11 train_loss:0.0122  val_loss:0.0125```
````

Comment: First 2 problems sound common for contrastive learning.Try decreasing your temperature and you should get a lower loss. No idea about the third problem

Comment: Thank you for your comment.